# How to create CSS gradient from the centre?

Tags: html, css

[image]
I want to create background gradient as above in the image (Load more news) and I have to add border style also. Please provide your suggestion on this.

Comment: Googling is so hard.

Comment: @zmwangx I tried but I didn't get the expected result. I never come across thin kind of design before. please tell me how to add those type of borders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use prefix on this

```css
div{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent, rgb(0, 255, 255), transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(left, transparent, rgb(0, 255, 255), transparent)
}
```

```html
<div/>
```